# NumberFormatException in GPS processing

Tags: android

I am having a weird problem.

I am developing a program to log GPS and sensor readings periodically. My friend runs the code on his machine using Eclipse Galileo 3.6 and it works perfectly fine for her.

When I run the code on my machine which has Eclipse Galileo 3.5.2 it shows service stopped unexpectedly.

We have the same JDK version. I am not able to figure out what may be the exact problem.

Please let me know what else information I need to give in order to fix the problem.

logcat

```
    I/ActivityManager( 1104): Start proc com.sensor.test for service com.sensor.test/.SensorReadings: pid=3539 uid=10057 gids={3003, 1015}
D/AndroidRuntime( 3539): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 3539): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d7e0)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3539): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 3539): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED flg=0x60000000 (has extras) } in com.sensor.test.SensorReadings$2@44770958
E/AndroidRuntime( 3539):    at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(ActivityThread.java:905)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3539):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3539):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3539):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3539):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3539):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3539):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3539):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3539):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3539):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3539): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime( 3539):    at com.sensor.test.SensorReadings$2.onReceive(SensorReadings.java:327)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3539):    at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(ActivityThread.java:892)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3539):    ... 9 more
W/ActivityManager( 1104): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{44b38508 com.sensor.test/.MainScreen}
D/WifiService( 1104): acquireWifiLockLocked: WifiLock{NetworkLocationProvider type=2 binder=android.os.Binder@44963d80}
D/LocationMasfClient( 1104): getNetworkLocation(): Location not found in cache, making network request
D/LocationMasfClient( 1104): getNetworkLocation(): Number of prefetched entries 10
E/LocationMasfClient( 1104): getNetworkLocation(): Returning *server* computed location with accuracy 28
D/libgps  ( 1104): GpsInterface_inject_location( 35.772249, -78.673950, 28.000 )
D/WifiService( 1104): releaseWifiLockLocked: WifiLock{NetworkLocationProvider type=2 binder=android.os.Binder@44963d80}
D/WifiService( 1104): acquireWifiLockLocked: WifiLock{NetworkLocationProvider type=2 binder=android.os.Binder@44963d80}
D/WifiService( 1104): releaseWifiLockLocked: WifiLock{NetworkLocationProvider type=2 binder=android.os.Binder@44963d80}
D/NativeCrypto( 1104): Freeing OpenSSL session
D/dalvikvm( 1104): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 22104 objects / 1169312 bytes in 128ms
D/NativeCrypto( 1104): Freeing OpenSSL session
I/Process ( 3539): Sending signal. PID: 3539 SIG: 9
W/InputManagerService( 1104): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44b40dd0
I/ActivityManager( 1104): Process com.sensor.test (pid 3539) has died.
```

The pertinent code for line 88 with parsing going on:

```
public void startService(){
        //startService(new Intent(MainScreen.this,SensorReadings.class));
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainScreen.this, SensorReadings.class);
        **intent.putExtra("lp", Integer.parseInt(""+longPeriod.getText()));// LINE 88**
        intent.putExtra("gp", Integer.parseInt(""+gpsPeriod.getText()));
        intent.putExtra("sp", Integer.parseInt(""+snrPeriod.getText()));
        //startActivity(intent);
        startService(intent);
    }
```

Thanks.
AG

Comment: What does logcat say with the service stops unexpectedly?

Comment: Also, are you using the same emulators?  This doesn't sound like an Eclipse problem.

Comment: @Glex Please try to use informative titles.  "I have a problem"  Tells us nothing.

Comment: Next: what is `longPeriod`? How's it declared?  Is it expected that it may return an empty string from `getText()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get why you are putting "".

So to be sure this is not the problem try either this:

- `intent.putExtra("lp", Integer.parseInt(longPeriod.getText()));
      intent.putExtra("gp", Integer.parseInt(gpsPeriod.getText()));
      intent.putExtra("sp", Integer.parseInt(snrPeriod.getText()));`

or

- `String lp = longPeriod.getText();

  String gp = gpsPeriod.getText();

  String sp = snrPeriod.getText();

  intent.putExtra("lp", Integer.parseInt(lp));
      intent.putExtra("gp", Integer.parseInt(gp));
      intent.putExtra("sp", Integer.parseInt(sp));`

The second way is better for debugging... so you can see what is actually happening.

Answer (score 1):

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 2934): java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
E/AndroidRuntime( 2934):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:412)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2934):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:382)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2934):    at com.sensor.test.MainScreen.startService(MainScreen.java:88)
```

Perhaps at line 88 in MainScreen.java, your `startService` method is calling `Integer.parseInt` with an empty string?

Can you show us the pertinent code?

Comment: @Glex - edit your question and include this code.  Use 4 spaces or highlight the code and click the format code button (`{}`).

Comment: sorry Bert ...Actually I showed the wrong part of the code. I will update the relevant code in the question asap.

Comment: @Glex - cool. Hope the all the "do this" and "do that" directives from everyone don't discourage you.  Everyone's just trying to help you get the most from this site.

Comment: I understand that...I really appreciate the effort....As u can make out I am a newbie....am having a good learning experience.

Comment: @Bert I tested the logcat at my friend and it shows the same error things but she does not gets this unexpectedly stop message.

Comment: @Glex - really?!! her logcat shows the same exception and it still works?? that's surprising since it seems like the exception would stop the `startService()` method in its tracks and never call `startService(intent)`.  How about using the debugger or using `Log.` messages to trace the method and check whether the method proceeds or stops after the exception is thrown. I'd put a `Log` after every line.  I'd run it on both your and their machines and compare the logs.

Comment: @Bert...I am sorry actually with with the similar log it does not work for her either.....When passing the required parameters she does not get that error and code works for her....I will update my log with the parameters...In the mean time rather than importing her project I am creating a new and then copying the code....hope it works with this trick.

Comment: @ Bert, Beasly, Matt, Myra ....Thanks a lot for your patience and support...Today I just updated my eclipse with available updates and then tried....everything worked fine then.....The reason I see is that probably my friend developed on 3.6 and there were some features (don't know what), were missing in my Eclipse. Anyways I just hope that I can contribute and help like u guys.....Thanks a lot

Comment: @Glex - glad you figured it out.  I would go ahead and post your findings as an answer (I would even accept it) so future people with similar problems can find it easily among the other possible causes/answers. BTW, the @ notification only notified me of your comment, not the others.   Only the first @-symbol triggers notification.